# Converting a DataTable Column from Boolean to Int

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable, data-conversion

I have written a program that uses an `OleDB` query to fill a `DataTable` which is then loaded into a MySQL Database using a `BulkLoader`. The issue I have come across is converting an OleDB Boolean type column into the equivalent in MySQL. I know there is no `BOOL` in MySQL, so I've tried using `TINYINT` with no luck. I believe the problem to be that I am giving the `BulkLoader` `TRUE` and `FALSE` when it needs a `1` or `0` to work.

This is what the column looks like in the intermediary CSV file;

[image]

What I thought would be a simple way of doing this is simply writing a `foreach` loop that goes through and makes every `TRUE = 1` and `FALSE = 2`, something like this;

```
foreach (DataRow column in dTable.Rows)
{
  if (Convert.ToBoolean(column[16]) == true)
  {
        column[16] = 1;
  }
  else
  {
        column[16] = 0;
  }
}
```

This however ends in an output of exactly the same as the image shown above, it still resolves everything to `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead of the `1` or `0`. I'm thinking now that I may have to convert the type of the `DataTable` column from boolean to integer but I am unsure of how to do that, or if it is the simplest way of doing this.

Comment: That's should be expected. The DataType of the column is boolean not int. Not sure but it seems that you need to change the datatype of the column or create a new column with the int type

Comment: Can't change the column type once it has data. Otherwise use `dTable.Columns[16].DataType = typeof(int);`

Answer (score 2):

Can't change the column type once it has data. But, can do something like this;

```
DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();
dtCloned.Columns["YouColumnName"].DataType = typeof(int);
foreach (DataRow row in dTable.Rows) 
    dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
```

Comment: Great stuff thanks. Just to add is there a way to make this non-hardcoded for the one column? I'm going to have many many boolean columns and it would be very time consuming to use this for every column I have.

Comment: Why -1? Please explain.